# Increase decimal digits displayed on a grid field

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone know how to increase the decimal digits displayed on a grid field?

When you click the `ADD STOCK ITEM` button on the `Sales Orders (SO301000)` screen, then click the `Sold Since` radio button, there is a field called `Last Unit Price` in the grid.

I would like to increase the decimal digits displayed from 2 to 3 decimals.

I tried customizing the data field using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, clicking on the field, and choosing `ACTIONS -> Customize Data Fields...` which yields this:

```
[PXCalcCurrency(typeof(SOSiteStatusSelected.curyInfoID), typeof(SOSiteStatusSelected.baseUnitPrice))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Unit Price", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
```

But I'm not sure if this is the place to do it.

[Here is a screenshot of the field I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90EWn.png)

Comment: Why do you want to change this one in particular and not all the prices field in the system? This should follow the setting set in Branches for decimal precision.

Comment: The Branches are set to 3 decimals and I can enter 3 decimals in the "Unit Price" field on the "Sales Orders (SO301000)" screen, but the field that I mention above only displays 2 decimals. The data is there, it just isn't getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can go Organization > Organization Structure > Branches and set Decimal Precision from 2 => 3

Comment: The Branches are set to 3 decimals and I can enter 3 decimals in the "Unit Price" field on the "Sales Orders (SO301000)" screen, but the field that I mention above only displays 2 decimals. The data is there, it just isn't getting displayed.